# Linked list function is printing NULL in first node instead of paths

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a program to read in a possible -v flag, a number key, and paths to put into a linked list from the command line. I have everything printing properly except the first node always prints NULL which fails my test cases. I've tried many different syntax and ways to write the _add function and _dump function but I can't quite figure it out. Here is the main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cplist.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int i, j;
    char *key;
    cplist *head = (cplist*) malloc(sizeof(cplist));

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-v") == 0){
        key = argv[2];
        for(i = 3; i <= argc; i++){
            cpl_add(head, argv[i]);
            j++;
        }
    } else {
        key = argv[1];
        for(i = 2; i <= argc; i++){
            cpl_add(head, argv[i]);
            j++;
        }
    }

    printf("key: %s\n", key);
    printf("paths parsed: %d\n", j);
    cpl_dump(head);

return(0);
}
```

Here is my list class:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "cplist.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

cplist *cpl_add(cplist *head, char *path){
    cplist *current = head;
    head->path = path;
    while(current->next != NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = (cplist*) malloc(sizeof(cplist));
    current->next->path = path;
    current->next->next = NULL;
}

void cpl_dump(cplist *head){
    cplist *current = head;
    head = head->next; 
    while(current->next != NULL){
        printf("%s \n", current->path);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

And this is what I'm outputting for example: ./a.out -v 1455 /tmp/ /tmp2/ /tmp3/

```
key: 1455
paths parsed: 4
(null)
/tmp/
/tmp2/
/tmp3/
```

May paths parsed should be 3 and (null) should not be printed but I have not been able to find any solution through trials

Comment: you should initialize the first node and j. What do you think head->path = path; does? walk this code with a debugger to see what is happening at each step.

Comment: The first time you call cpl_add() current->next is evaluated before it is assigned a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

First, you don't set the initial values for the head node.  When you first try to add a new node, the value of `head->next` is indeterminate.  You should initialize its fields:

```
cplist *head = (cplist*) malloc(sizeof(cplist));
head->path = NULL;
head->next = NULL;
```

You also don't initialize `j` before incrementing it.  Initialize it to 0.

When you're reading in arguments:

```
for(i = 3; i <= argc; i++){
```

You read one too many.  Change `<=` to `<`.

Then in your printing function:

```
void cpl_dump(cplist *head){
    cplist *current = head;
    head = head->next; 
    while(current->next != NULL){
        printf("%s \n", current->path);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

You start `current` at `head` and count from there, so the first value printed is the one in the dummy head node.  Presumably the next line was supposed to address this, but you set the wrong pointer.  You instead want:

```
cplist *current = head->next;
```

Finally, the condition stops you from reading the contents of the last node in the list.  You instead want:

```
while(current != NULL){
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I needed. The pointers and how to initialize the node values are what confused me the most but this clears it up